# How can I easily take selfies with a Canon PowerShot SX720 HS?

Tags: canon, compact-cameras, self-portrait

How can I take a selfie with this camera and what equipment will I need to purchase to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is special about this camera which would make it so something extra would need to be purchased in order to take a picture of yourself?

Comment: Please define "selfie". Seriously, I mean it. In my mind, a selfie is a picture of yourself, taken while holding the camera yourself. If that's what you mean, then we don't need to explain how to hold a camera backwards or point it at a mirror and take a picture. But if you mean something different than my understanding (which I'm pretty sure is fairly close to universally correct), we need a clarification of terms.

Comment: An HDMI cable and TV?

Answer (score 1):

This camera has no rotating screen, so you cannot see the photo while taking it. You'll have to use common sense and guesswork to figure out which way to point it.

Hold it out at arms length, with the lens pointing straight at your face. Then push the button. Review the image on the screen and if the framing is off, try again.

The camera is small enough that you might be able to use a selfie stick and the self timer feature of the camera.

If you want to see the screen while framing the photo, then get yourself a mirror.

Comment: Use a tripod and a 10 second delayed shutter!